# How to extract number from a string in mongodb query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

The only problem with commented query is that "$DAMAGE_PROPERTY" is written in 0K, 1K, 250K, 5.20M format, and the $todecimal/$toDouble aren't able to convert that to an integer. My purpose is to extract number out of string in the query itself and not iterate over the result array.

```
try {
        const db = client.db(dbName);
        let collection = db.collection("Storm");
        let query = {
          STATE: "INDIANA",
          EVENT_TYPE: event,
          DAMAGE_PROPERTY: { $nin: ["", null] },
          YEAR: { $gte: startYear, $lte: endYear },
        };

        // --> aggregation failed.

        // let res = await collection
        //   .aggregate([
        //     { $match: query },
        //     {
        //       $project: {
        //         document: "$$ROOT",
        //         damage: {
        //           $sum: {
        //             $toDouble: "$DAMAGE_PROPERTY", //Cause of Error: no conversion
        //           },
        //         },
        //       },
        //     },
        //   ])
        //   .toArray();
        // console.log(res);

        // ---> Solution I want to avoid
        let res = await collection.find(query).toArray();
    
        var totalDamage = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
          totalDamage += parseFloat(res[i].DAMAGE_PROPERTY);
        }
        console.log(
          `Total Damage to property in Indiana from ${startYear} to ${endYear} due to ${event} is ${totalDamage}K`
        );
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } finally {
        client.close();
      }
```

Test Data in json:

```
{
        "BEGIN_YEARMONTH": 200809,
        "BEGIN_DAY": 14,
        "BEGIN_TIME": 830,
        "END_YEARMONTH": 200809,
        "END_DAY": 14,
        "END_TIME": 1030,
        "EPISODE_ID": 21247,
        "YEAR": 2008,
        "DEATHS_DIRECT": 0,
        "DEATHS_INDIRECT": 0,
        "DAMAGE_PROPERTY": "5.20M",
    },
```

Comment: It would greatly help your question by adding sample data.

Comment: @Xavier is `DAMAGE_PROPERTY` an array of strings in "{some_number}K" format?

Comment: Hey @DheemanthBhat I was going through your sol but DAMAGE_PROPERTY is just property in an objects array. I have provided one of the object out of many in the latest edit

Comment: So you want the sum of all the documents then?

Comment: Yes i want to sum all the documents and display output as totalDamage. Which is why in the second solution, I simply iterated over the found documents and displayed the sum.

Comment: Are there any other characters possible other than `K` and `M` in DAMAGE_PROPERTY? Check the updated answer

Comment: No! Great sol can you explain me a little over the $cond part?

Comment: Check the updated answer of explanation

Comment: hey @DheemanthBhat i think I'm asking for too much but is there a way to multiply these numbers by a quantity? For instance if the string is 5.20M, M is equivalent to 100. So the actual damage added to the sum should be 520. I dont know how to add $mul to your query

Comment: For "M" its 100, What about "K"?

Comment: For K it'll be 10.

Comment: Jackpot! I have given two answers. New one with switch/case style and old answer updated for your new requirement.

Comment: omg! I need to read about queries more, thank you so much for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing another solution to avoid clutter/confuse, Answer #1:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            DAMAGE_PROPERTY: {
                $push: {
                    $let: {
                        vars: {
                            damage: {
                                $toDouble: {
                                    $substrBytes: ["$DAMAGE_PROPERTY", 0, { $subtract: [{ $strLenCP: "$DAMAGE_PROPERTY" }, 1] }]
                                }
                            },
                            unit: {
                                $substrBytes: ["$DAMAGE_PROPERTY", { $subtract: [{ $strLenCP: "$DAMAGE_PROPERTY" }, 1] }, 1]
                            }
                        },
                        in: {
                            $switch: {
                                branches: [
                                    {
                                        case: { $eq: ["$$unit", "M"] },
                                        then: {
                                            $multiply: ["$$damage", 100]
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        case: { $eq: ["$$unit", "K"] },
                                        then: {
                                            $multiply: ["$$damage", 10]
                                        }
                                    },
                                    // You can have more cases in future
                                ],
                                default: "Error: No unit matched." // or 0
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            totalDamage: { $sum: "$DAMAGE_PROPERTY" }
        }
    }
]);
```

Output:

```js
{
    "totalDamage" : 615
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** based on coments:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            DAMAGE_PROPERTY: {
                $push: {
                    $cond: {
                        if: { $lt: [{ $size: { $split: ["$DAMAGE_PROPERTY", "K"] } }, 2] },
                        then: {
                            $multiply: [
                                {
                                    $toDouble: { $first: { $split: ["$DAMAGE_PROPERTY", "M"] } }
                                },
                                100
                            ]
                        },
                        else: {
                            $multiply: [
                                {
                                    $toDouble: { $first: { $split: ["$DAMAGE_PROPERTY", "K"] } }
                                },
                                10
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            totalDamage: { $sum: "$DAMAGE_PROPERTY" }
        }
    }
]);
```

Output for the updated query

```
{
    "totalDamage" : 615
}
```

What is `$cond` doing?

```
STEP 1: Try to split DAMAGE_PROPERTY by "K".
// Example 1: split_result = ["5.2M"]
// Example 2: split_result = ["9.5", ""]

if the length of split_result array is less than 2:
    Try to split DAMAGE_PROPERTY by "M"
    // For example: split_result = ["5.2", ""]
    typecast the first string to decimal
    return the result
else:
    Split the DAMAGE_PROPERTY by "K"
    // For example: split_result = ["9.5", ""]
    typecast the first string to decimal
    return the result
```

Try this:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            DAMAGE_PROPERTY: {
                $push: {
                    $toDouble: {
                        $cond: {
                            if: { $lt: [{ $size: { $split: ["$DAMAGE_PROPERTY", "K"] } }, 2] },
                            then: { $first: { $split: ["$DAMAGE_PROPERTY", "M"] } },
                            else: { $first: { $split: ["$DAMAGE_PROPERTY", "K"] } }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            totalDamage: { $sum: "$DAMAGE_PROPERTY" }
        }
    }
]);
```

Output:

```js
{
    "totalDamage" : 14.7
}
```

Test data:

```js
/* 1 createdAt:3/12/2021, 3:22:08 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604b39c84b5860176c2254e2"),
    "DAMAGE_PROPERTY" : "5.20M"
},

/* 2 createdAt:3/12/2021, 3:22:08 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604b39c84b5860176c2254e3"),
    "DAMAGE_PROPERTY" : "9.5K"
}
```